# What is the Performance impact of Sealed Classes in the context of Android?

Tags: android, performance, kotlin, enums, sealed-class

In Android, it is advisable to refrain from using enum due to performance issue. This is true until recently, where it was announced in Google IO 2018 that enums are now safe to use though avoiding them is still advisable for a more performant app.

My question is:

Can we use kotlin sealed classes extensively in android?

It seems like sealed classes are extensions of enums. If so, should we use sealed classes similar to enums?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The advice to stay away from `enum` on Android is exaggerated. Avoiding enums makes sense for the Android APIs: they heavily use special constants, there are very many of those objects live in an application, and they are performance-critical.

Your custom application code would probably want to use just a few enums to express entities from business logic. Creating a dozen, or even a few hundred, `enum` instances will leave an imperceptible footprint.

The same advice extends to sealed classes: by all means use them and improve the quality of your code. Stop to think about your choice only if you plan to embark on building a 100 KLOC application with thousands upon thousands of enum-like constants and classes.

Answer (score 8):

### Enums

**Garbage Collection**

Under the hood, enums are static members of the class, so they don't get garbage collected. They stay in memory for the lifespan of your app. This can be an upside or a downside.

The garbage collection process is expensive in terms of CPU usage. The same is true for object creation, you don't want to create the same objects again and again. So, with enums, you save the cost of garbage collection as well as object creation. This is the upside.

The downside is that the enums stay in memory even when they are not in use, this can keep the memory occupied all the time.

**Factors to Consider**

You don't need to worry about all this, if you have 100 to 200 enums in your app. But when you have more than that, you have a decision to make whether you should go for enums depending on the facts such as the number of enums, whether they will be in use all the time and the amount of memory allocated to your JVM.

**Comparison**

The comparison of enum values is faster in the `when` expression because under the hood it uses `tableswitch` to compare the objects.

**Android**

In Android, when the optimization is enabled, the Proguard converts the enums that don't have functions and properties to integers. This way, you get the type-safety of the enums at compile-time and the performance of the ints at runtime!

---

### Sealed Classes

**Garbage Collection**

Sealed classes are just regular classes with the only exception that they need to be extended in the same package and the same compilation unit. So, their performance is equivalent to regular classes.

Objects of the subtypes of the sealed classes get garbage collected like the objects of regular classes. So, you have to bear the cost of garbage collection as well as object creation.

**Factors to Consider**

When you have the low memory constraints, you may consider using sealed classes instead of enums, if you need thousands of objects. Because the garbage collector can collect the objects when the memory is low and the objects are not in use.

If you use `object` declaration for extending the sealed class, the objects act as singletons and they won't be garbage collected, this behaviour is similar to enums. But there is an additional cost of loading the associated classes and keeping them in memory because `object` declarations have associated classes with the same names as the objects under the hood.

**Comparison**

The comparison of sealed class' types is slower in the `when` expression because under the hood it uses `instanceof` to compare the types. The speed difference between enums and sealed classes, in this case, is very little though. It matters only when you are comparing thousands of constants in a loop.

**Android**

Proguard doesn't have any integer optimization like enums for sealed classes. So, if you want to have just constants without functions and properties in Android, sticking to enums is a better idea.

---

That's it! Hope that helps.

Answer (score 4):

The performance impact of sealed classes is the same as for any other classes. If you create an instance of a class extending a sealed class, it will be a new instance, so it will need to be garbage-collected. If you have an `object` extending a sealed class, it will be a singleton and will not need to be collected (just like an enum constant)..